# Adding a css class to select using @Html.DropDownList()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building my first MVC application after years of doing webforms, and for some reason I am not able to make this work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", String.Empty, new {@class="textbox"} )
```

Error message:

`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<SPDR.Models.Bug>`' does not contain a definition for `DropDownList` and the best extension method overload `System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, object)` has some invalid arguments

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You aren't using an overload that takes those parameters. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Looking at the controller, and learing a bit more about how MVC actually works, I was able to make sense of this.

My view was one of the auto-generated ones, and contained this line of code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", string.Empty)
```

To add html attributes, I needed to do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID, new { @class="dropdown" })
```

Thanks again to @Laurent for your help, I realise the question wasn't as clear as it could have been...

**UPDATE:**

A better way of doing this would be to use [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) where possible, that way you don't rely on a magic string for the name attribute

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PriorityID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID, new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

Comment: I'm using your solution (my view is auto-generated too), but when in edit view, I've lost my selected value, could you help me?

@Html.DropDownList("StateGroupID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StateGroupID, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: @Willy, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "lost my selected value" - do you mean the selected value is not being posted to the server correctly? Please see my edit for a possible solution...

Comment: when i edited the record, dropdownlist is empty, it should be bind to a value. I've found the solution by passing null value at 2nd parameter @Html.DropDownList("StateGroupID", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: how about multiple classes?

Comment: It's ok. But if you want a default value like `-select-` with you list then you need to modify it must like `@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID, String.Empty,  new { @class="dropdown" })`

Answer (score 40):

As the signature from the error message implies, the second argument must be an IEnumerable, more specifically, an IEnumerable of SelectListItem. It is the list of choices. You can use the SelectList type, which is a IEnumerable of SelectListItem.
For a list with no choices:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", new List<SelectListItem>(), new {@class="textbox"} )
```

For a list with a few choices:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "PriorityID", 
    new List<SelectListItem> 
    { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = 1 }, 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Low",  Value = 0 },
    }, 
    new {@class="textbox"})
```

Maybe this tutorial can be of help: [How to create a DropDownList with ASP.NET MVC](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Laurent, unfortunately I'm still having problems. Using your line of code I get the following error: 

System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

This line works, I get the select tag, but I just want to add a css class:

@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", String.Empty)

Comment: You're right, I've changed to `new List<SelectListItem>()`. SelectList is actually a helper class to help you create a list of choices from a different list of objects. See the tutorial I added to my post.

Comment: Thanks, that does work however using overload #2 (string name, string optionLabel) my dropdown is populated automatically with the records from my Priority table. That is exactly what I want, I just need to add the css class - but it seems there is no overload that allows that?!

Answer (score 19):

If you are add more than argument ya dropdownlist in Asp.Net MVC.
When you Edit record or pass value in view bag.

Use this it will be work:-

```
@Html.DropDownList("CurrencyID",null,String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control-mandatory" })
```

Comment: You made my day @mohita

Answer (score 9):

There are some options in constructors look,
if you don't have dropdownList and you wanna insert CSS class you can use like

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "Choose-Category", new {@class="form-control"})
```

in this case Country is the name of your dropdown, null is for you aren't passing any generic list from your controller "Choose-Category" is selected item and last one in CSS class
if you don't wanna select any default option so simple replace "Choose-Category" with ""

Answer (score 6):

You Can do it using jQuery

```
  $("select").addClass("form-control")
```

here, Select is- html tag,
     Form-control is- class name

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SupplierId", "Select Supplier")
```

and here, SupplierId is ViewBagList,
         Select Supplier is - Display Name

Answer (score 4):

Simply Try this

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID,  new { @class="dropdown" })
```

But if you want a default value or no option value then you must have to try this one, because `String.Empty` will select that no value for you which will work as a `-select-` as default option

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID, String.Empty, new { @class="dropdown" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductTypeID",null,"",new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "country", 
    new[] {
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "IN", Text = "India" },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "US", Text = "United States" }
    }, 
    "Country",
    new { @class = "form-control",@selected = Model.Country}
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", null, new { @class="form-control"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Id", null, new { @class = "ct-js-select ct-select-lg" })
```