# DropDownList not selected in Edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag, dropdownlistfor

I Created Controller with "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" and modify "DropDownList" code in "Edit" view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.prdepno,(SelectList)ViewBag.prdepno, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

in Controller use ViewBag

```
personal personal = db.personals.Find(id);

ViewBag.prdepno = new SelectList(db.prdeps, "prdepno", "prdepdes", emp_map.prdepno);
```

no error ,but dropdownlist not selected

I lookup from [Adding a css class to select using @Html.DropDownList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367344/adding-a-css-class-to-select-using-html-dropdownlist) 
and other question try to do that, but It not work (for me)

I don't know to do
(sorry, in my communication.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do not use the same name for the model property and the ViewBag `SelectList` property

Comment: thank for edit @JohnSaunders , It first post for me

Comment: Thank you for @StephenMuecke, It works.. (I did not notice the details here.)

Comment: Note also the last parameter of `SelectList` is not required if your using `DropDownListFor()` to bind to a property. The selected option is based on the value of your model property so its ignored.

Comment: Thank you for Note @StephenMuecke, I will learn it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the name of ViewBag Object

```
personal personal = db.personals.Find(id);

ViewBag.DwPrdeps= new SelectList(db.prdeps, "prdepno", "prdepdes", emp_map.prdepno);
```

after that use `ViewBag.DwPrdeps` in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.prdepno,(SelectList)ViewBag.DwPrdeps, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you @MANISH , I have noticed more

Answer (score 0):

### **Try With this code It's Work properly**

******Code Generate/ Model******

```
public class CityList
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
    }
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCity()
{
    IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Dhaka", Value = "dhk" },
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Chittagong", Value = "CTG" }
    };
    return items;
}
```

***For Create***

```
ViewBag.city = new SelectList(GetCity(), "Text", "Value");

@Html.DropDownList("city", null, "--Select city--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2", required = "required" })
```

***For edit***

```
ViewBag.city = new SelectList(GetCity(), "Text", "Value",model.city);

@Html.DropDownList("city", null, "--Select city--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2", required = "required" })
```

*You Can Try This it's work fine.*