# c# MVC @Html.DropDownListFor how do you add CSS & title Option list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to generate the following HTML using @Html.DropDownListFor
I need to add a class to an option

```
<select class="selectpicker">
<option  title="food">Mustard</option>
<option  title="food" class="special">Ketchup</option>
<option  title="food">Relish</option>
<option  title="drink">fanta</option>
<option  title="drink" class="special">Red bull</option>
</select>
```

Comment: SelectListItem  doesn't  have the ability to add extra attributes to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way is **for loop**. Cannot do this with @Html.DropDownListFor

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    @foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
    {
        <option title="@item.Value" @(new[]{"Ketchup","Red bull"}.Any(x => x == item.Text) ? "class=special" : "") @(item.Selected ? "selected" : "")>@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PriorityID, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.PriorityID, new { @class = "dropdown" })

Comment: This is a Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367344/adding-a-css-class-to-select-using-html-dropdownlist

Comment: this adds a class to the select element not the option element