# ASP MVC4 : Selected option is not at top in @Html.DropDownList with html attributres

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I have a edit page in my "~/viewName/Controllers/edit.cshtml" page.
From Controller's edit action the DropDownList data comes from this Viewbag :

```
 ViewBag.PROJECT_NO = new SelectList(db.TRAINING_PROJECT, "PROJECT_NO", "PROJECT_NAME",
 training_new.PROJECT_NO);
```

When I go to the edit page then the default

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO", String.Empty)
```

is displayed with it's corresponding selected values and other values at the bottom. When I add some html attributes like class, id, required, disabled then from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24780834/3399176) I did the bellowed code in my "edit.cshtml"

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO", null, String.Empty, new {@class = "form-control input-sm",
@id = "ex2" })
```

And now my DropDownList is not displaying the selected value. Rather it is displaying null value, means blank as selected value and other values at the bottom. But here I want to see the selected one. The bellowed image will describe more about the default output and the second output

[image]

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov please can you help me from this stuck?

Comment: Why you are passing `null` as a list of options?

Comment: Is `PROJECT_NO` a property in your model?. If so you need to assign your SelectList to a `ViewBag` property which has a different name from the property name

Comment: Oh, I forgot it is a view bag with project_no and project_name.  ViewBag.PROJECT_NO = new SelectList(db.TRAINING_PROJECT, "PROJECT_NO", "PROJECT_NAME", training_new.PROJECT_NO);  Thanks

Comment: But do you have a model with a property named `PROJECT_NO` (in which case you are doing this wrong)

Comment: means? please decribe @StephenMuecke

Comment: For the 3rd time, do your model have a property named `PROJECT_NO`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**simply try this:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO", null, new {@class = "form-control input-sm",@id = "ex2" })
```

when it is written

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO", null, String.Empty, new {@class = "form-control input-sm",@id = "ex2" })
```

it takes String.Empty as DropDownList header.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong overload, you need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO",
                   ViewBag.PROJECT_NO as SelectList,
                   new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "ex2" })
```

### SideNote:

You don't need to prefix **`@`** before id, we put if for `class` because `class` is a reserved word in c#, so for using it as variable we need to prefix it **`@`**

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = 
    from c in db.TRAINING_PROJECT
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = (c.ProjectId == 1), //put your condition here 
        Text = c.ProjectName , //MyAssumption, put yours here
        Value = c.ProjectId //My assumption, put yours here
    };

ViewBag.PROJECT_NO = selectList;
```

Comment: What difference would this make. OP is already generating the `SelectList` correctly

Comment: I have tested the scenario mentioned above, it works fine with the solution I have mentioned. Personally I like this approach than the ViewBag approach. I have read where lot of people on SO suggest this approach it self.

Comment: And OP's current usage also works fine! This has nothing to do with the problem (the problem is the usage of `@Html.DropDownList()` in the view). You just showing a different way of generating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (and you ARE using ViewBag)

Comment: My solution is not dependent on ViewBag, if you notice it. Secondly I do-not doubt the solution given by others. Its just another way of doing it.

Comment: And neither is OP's solution dependent on `ViewBag`

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("PROJECT_NO", null, new {@class = "form-control input-sm",@id = "ex2" });
Here PROJECT_NO, has to come from ViewBag. If I understand correctly
The DropDownList helper  select list requires IEnumerable<SelectListItem >, either explicitly or implicitly. You can pass IEnumerable<SelectListItem >  explicitly to the DropDownList helper or you can add the  IEnumerable<SelectListItem >  to the ViewBag using the same name for the SelectListItem   as the model property. So it was the latter way here. Anyways there are always multiple approaches to same problem because its not history