# How to apply boostrap style to .aspx view?

Tags: asp.net, aspx-user-control

a need apply ***boostrap*** style in mi ***DropDownList*** only in the view, not my model

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
            Pais:
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%: Html.DropDownList("CodPais", String.Empty)  %>
            <p class="label label-danger"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodPais) %> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

***someone has documentation on how to apply bootstrap in visual .aspx***

***i try:***

[image]

Comment: Are you just asking how to specify HTML attributes (such as a `class` value) when using `Html.DropDownList()`?  Or something else?

Comment: @Rodrigo try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37513561/713789